# rhythmic stress double check please?

Tags: rhythm, drums

Lately I am reading Jack Perricone's Melody in Songwriting, and in it there is a chapter dedicated to 'rhythmic stress'.

His opinion is that rhythm is a skeleton to a song, the most basic part, and I've come to understand his point of view.

So I am spending some time on studying rhythmic stress, and as I am a beginner and all, I just wished that someone more experienced could double check rhythmic stress I have drawn.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if you put the right symbols in the right places? If so, you'll have to explain what the symbols mean. I doubt they are widely known in music because I've never seen them before (after 45+ years as a musician).

Comment: I believe `/` is a primary stress, `//` is a secondary stress, and `–` is an unstressed note. This is what I've seen in songwriting/poetry educational materials.

Comment: Generally speaking, stress goes as follows: (4/4) Beat 1, most, beat 3 next. Beats 2 and 4 similar, but less than beat 2.  (3/4) Beat 1 most, 2 & 3 the same. (6/8) beat 1 most, beat 4 next. (12/8) beat 1 most, beat 7 next, beats 4 and 10 similar, but less than 7. I hope that's for snare drum - its placement is how I prefer to write it - middle line! BUT - this looks like homework - and we don't do homework for folk on this site, sorry! Hence no answer.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure we really *do* have an official policy against homework "as such," and IMO this question doesn't fit even the unofficial one. [We did talk about it, including you!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/is-homework-a-close-reason) That said, I'm voting to close as unclear until edited because this seems to be a specialized shorthand used only by one book and not explained in the question. Sean, please edit!